# Uniden BC780XLT Radio scanner, unknown modification

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, radio, frequency-modulation

I recently purchased an old Uniden BC780XLT scanner. It has been modified replacing two smd resistor with THT resistors with different values. I am curious about this modification: what does it do?

[image: [Picture of the modification](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdnjvflmfgcmhz3/Modification.jpg?dl=0)]

I found the schematic for this radio:  [Schematics](http://radiopics.com/-%20PHP%20-/1.%20Manuals/Bearcat-Uniden/Bearcat%20BC780XLT%20(Schematic).php)

In particular, I think the modification involves this part of the circuit with the OPAMP chip IC11 (JRC 3403A)
[image: schematic excerpt]
[Datasheet](https://www.njr.com/semicon/PDF/NJM3403A_E.pdf)

The two resistor new values are 27kohm and 1.2Mohm, the old ones are 22k and 120k.
From the block diagram of the radio (one of the first pages of the schematics), the IC11 (the circuit in question), is a buffer stage after the FM demodulator.

Help me solve the mystery. The radio works, but I'm still curious!

Comment: That schematic is virtually unreadable. My best guess is that the mod changes the behavior of the squelch function -- making it more or less sensitive to noise than the original design.

Comment: I think you may be right, I noticed I need to lower the squelch level a lot to let through signals, compared to what demonstrated in some youtube videos. So possibly it made the squelch more sensitive, as you said. I don't find it particularly useful though, I wonder if it will let me lower it enough to let weak signals in.